# how to convert js string to python string?

Tags: javascript, python, string, escaping

In js , all items after backslash will be escaped:

```
a = "\s" will be "s"<br/>
```

But in python , the backslash preserve:

```
a = "\s" will be "\s"<br/>
```

So if I send "\s" to python , how can I make it print "s" only?

---

Well , I'm writing a web spider and catch some js code :

```
<script>var a = "\s"</script>
```

I pass the string "var a = "\s"" to python processor , but can't figure out an elegant way to make a string in python identical to "var a" (can not simply erase the letter "\" because the real case is far more complicate than this...)

Comment: How are you "sending it to Python"?

Comment: What you're describing is just how string literals are written in programs. When you "send" the string, it just sends the data, the literal representation is irrelevant.